# Whitelist SMTP after hacking?

Tags: email, smtp, spam, email-bounces

My Wordpress (hosted on GoDaddy) was hacked via SQL injection a few months ago. I hired a consultant to help me clean out WP and the site is functioning back to normal. Unfortunately, as part of the hack, they took over my SMTP server and sent out a ton of spam mail.

Now, whenever I send email to a new address, it immediately bounces back as **552: Message rejected for spam or virus content**. It should be noted that to addresses that I used to mail before (friends, colleagues, etc), the messages get through just fine. It's only when I try to contact people that have never received a message from me. I am assuming that this is related to my domain being blacklisted as a spam provider.

Some basic research indicated that this message might be specific to GoDaddy and I might need their help. Some sites even suggested leaving GoDaddy altogether. I doubt that would help in my scenario because the spam email was tied to my domain name, so I think my overall domain name is "bad".

What are some of the steps that I can take to try and get my domain off any blacklists? Is there a way for me to verify that my domain has been blacklisted? I really haven't dealt with anything like this before and just want to be able to send email from my domain again.

Comment: It is completely irresponsible for @EEAA to make this as a duplicate - clearly the question was not read

Comment: Fixed it for you... "It is completely responsible for @EEAA to make this as a duplicate - clearly the question was read"

Comment: While the **question** is from someone wanting to send newsletters rather than personal email, the **answers** are equally relevant for you. You should read them, and also the two questions linked at the top of the duplicate question.

Comment: @DMS I read (and understood) your entire question. Twice. If you would like to discuss topicality of this question, you're always welcome to post on meta.serverfault.com. Clearly state your reasoning and let the community weigh in. If they're in favor of re-opening this question, I'll gladly do it.

Comment: If you feel that closing the question was wrong, you can post to [meta] and explain your reasoning.

Comment: If your system was hacked, then you need to restore from backups. One cannot clean up everything from a compromised system.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: Wrong canonical question :)

Comment: @EEAA Show me where the links you sent address a 552 error specifically. You are being completely irresponsible about this.

Comment: @DMS Sending email is sending email. It doesn't matter whether it's a newsletter or personal email - the things you'll need to do to avoid having your emails tagged as spam are the same regardless. As two of us mentioned above, if you would like to argue your case that this question should be re-opened, you're welcome to post on meta.serverfault.com.

Comment: I'll also mention that personal email systems are off-topic here.